# How to save a simple feature with several geometries?

Tags: r, geometry, gis, r-sf

I would like to organise my data as a simple feature object using the `sf` package in R that has several geometric columns, for example a polygon, its centroid and its buffer, that all share the same attributes.

I have difficulties saving such an object to disk. For example this is what I get if I attempt to save it as a shapefile with `st_write()`:

```
Error in clean_columns(as.data.frame(obj), factorsAsCharacter) : 
  list columns are only allowed with raw vector contents

Warning:
1: In abbreviate_shapefile_names(obj) :
  Field names abbreviated for ESRI Shapefile driver
2: In clean_columns(as.data.frame(obj), factorsAsCharacter) :
  Dropping column(s) nghbrhd,landscp of class(es) sfc_POLYGON;sfc,sfc_POLYGON;sfc
```

Of course I could split it into several objects that each have one geometry and all attributes but I find this more messy and error-prone that having all data in one file.

How can I (best) save such an object?

Comment: Do you just need to read/write data from R?

Comment: yes, I am working in R only

Comment: If you're only working in R, have you tried `saveRDS()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When saving objects via `sf::st_write()` you have to respect the context of your output object; two popular file formats - [ESRI Shapefile / *.shp](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/shapefile.html) and [OGC GeoPackage / *.gpkg](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gpkg.html) - specifically allow only a single geometry per saved shapefile.

This is a feature, not a bug, of the output file format.

If your workflow requires saving of objects with multiple geometries consider either R specific format `saveRDS()` or if exchange with other spatial tools is required one of the formats that allow multiple geometries per object - [PostgreSQL / PostGIS](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pg.html) database is what I would use in such a situation.

Comment: Yes I was kind of aware that shapefile would not be able to make sense of multiple geometries. saveRDS() worked just fine, thank you!